# How to add conditions in find() function?

Tags: sql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

This is my query :

```
Doctrine::getTable('Registar')->find('1');
```

'1' is an ID

And I would like to add several others ID with `IN` condition to have a request like this :

```
SELECT c.id AS c__id, c.created_at AS c__created_at, c.updated_at AS c__updated_at FROM registar c WHERE c.id IN ('1','2','3')
```

It is possible with `find` function to add this condition ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` is just a short method to retrieve one row using the primary key (in your case `id`).

If you want to *more complex* query, you have to use `where` method, like this:

```
Doctrine::getTable('Registar')
  ->whereIn('id', array('1','2','3'))
  ->execute();
```

It's better to define this method inside `RegistarTable.class.php`, like that:

```
public function findByIds($ids)
{
  return $this->createQuery()
    ->whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->execute();
}
```

And then call it using:

```
Doctrine::getTable('Registar')->findByIds(array('1','2','3'));
```

Comment: You can also use the `findBy` or `findByDql` method